# Jquery Img Star Rating

Tags: jquery

I have an `img` with a `span` that contains multiple star imgs. and I am trying to create a `on.Click` function that will change the `src` of the `img` when clicked. Unfortunatlly, I think i'm doing it wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var starRating

      $('.rating').on({
          'click': function() {
            $('.rating').attr('src', 'second.jpg');

          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">
  <img src="img.png">
  <span class="rating">
      <img src="staroff.png">
      <img src="staroff.png">
      <img src="staroff.png">
      <img src="staroff.png">
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your code. For instance, to bind a click event listener, the syntax should be `$(selector).on("click", function() {...`, as opposed to how you've written it.

Also, instead of selecting `.rating` to listen to click events on, you could select specific images to listen for click events using: `.rating > img`.

Finally, `$('.rating').attr('src',...` doesn't work because `.rating` points to a span, which doesn't have an `src` attribute. To set the `src` on the image being clicked, you can simply set it using `$(this).attr('src',...`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var starRating

  $('.rating > img').on('click', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', '//placehold.it/50/ffff00');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">
  
  <span class="rating">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
  </span>
</div>
```

### Update

In order to make *starring* work, i.e. select all images before given image, when an image is clicked, you can use jQuery's `.prevAll`. Also, to reset the src value of the images appearing after given image, you could use `.nextAll`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var starRating

  $('.rating > img').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prevAll().attr('src', '//placehold.it/50/ffff00');
    $(this).attr('src', '//placehold.it/50/ffff00');
    
    // Set other images to original one.
    $(this).nextAll().attr("src", "//placehold.it/50/00ff00");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">

  <span class="rating">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50/00ff00">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: For example, is it possible to when clicking on the 3rd, the other imgs change as well. and not only one? @Nisarg

Comment: @xTuckii Yup. Updated my answer to show how you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **FontAwesome** icons instead of images, all you have to do is to include the CDN, then give a certain `class` name to the `<i>` tag:

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c6435311fd.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-star"><i>
```

---

Now responding to your question I will suggest you to first handle the `click` event using one of the following syntax:

1. `$(".fa-star").on("click",function(){/*DoYourStuffsHere*/});`
2. `$(".fa-star")click(function(){/*DoYourStuffsHere*/});`

After that, we should implement the code that change the color of the stars. For that, my idea is to get the `index` of the clicked element using the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) jQuery function, next we'll change the `color` of the elements that have an index between `0` and the clicked index:

```
 var index=$(this).index();
    for(var i=0;i<=index;i++)
    {
      $(".fa-star:eq("+i+")").css("color","yellow");
    }
```

Another `loop` will reset the color of the elements that have an index between the `clickedIndex+1` and the index of the last element.

```
      for(var i=index+1;i<$(".fa-star").length;i++)
      {
        $(".fa-star:eq("+i+")").css("color","black");
      }
```

Finally here is a code snippet that illustrate all what i've said:

```js
$(".fa-star").on("click",function(){
var index=$(this).index();
  for(var i=0;i<=index;i++)
  {
    $(".fa-star:eq("+i+")").css("color","yellow");
  }
for(var i=index+1;i<$(".fa-star").length;i++)
  {
    $(".fa-star:eq("+i+")").css("color","black");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c6435311fd.js"></script>
<div id="img">
    <span class="rating">
        <i id="star1" class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i id="star2" class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i id="star3" class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i id="star4" class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i id="star5" class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, I'd do this:

```
<div id="img">
    <img src="img.png">
    <span class="rating">
        <img id="star1" src="staroff.png">
        <img id="star2" src="staroff.png">
        <img id="star3" src="staroff.png">
        <img id="star4" src="staroff.png">
    </span>
</div>
```

Then the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var starRating = 0;

    $('.rating img').click(function(e) {
        starRating = parseInt(e.target.id.substring(4));

        for (var i = 1; i <= starRating.length; i++) {
            $('#star'+i).attr('src', 'staron.png')
        }
    });
});
```

Or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding.